# Unable to launch app issue after updating to Xcode 11

Tags: ios13, xcode11, swift5

Unable to launch com.***.*******
Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos

### Code: -12

The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.***.*******'
Domain: DTXMessage

### Code: 1